# text output in separate window

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, subprocess, output

I have a python script that runs under Windows in a cmd window. It's using logging and calling several programs using the subprocess method in a standard way. Now I want to have multiprocessing of these subprocess calls. But the log of all processes is a bit confusing while running. I want:

- having still a log in the main cmd window and log file of everything
- having a separate window for duplicate text output for each process

Apart from the multiprocessing, how would I duplicate the text output?

```
pro = process.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.STDOUT, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
while True:
    line = pro.stdout.readline()
    logging.info(line)
```

Comment: You should look into using named pipes. In Linux you would generally do this with `mkfifo`. You can create a pipe and `tee` output to it, which will duplicate the output to the pipe where it can be read by another process. I'm not sure what the Windows equivalent would be but someone here can likely help with that. In the meantime, try researching "Windows Named Pipes"